# How to add add row number to NetSuite saved searches

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I have a Transactions saved search that sums an amount over a number of grouped fields:

Results window looks like this (left out a number of Groups for simplicity) :
[image]

I would like to add a row_number to the result, such that the search result is ordered by a column that will always give the same ordering.

Is this possible?

I tried this, but the rownum column is not shown in the result :

[image]

@ehcanadian, I also tried this :
[image]
and this
[image]

but then it just doesn't show that column in the preview.

Comment: You'll still need to use a summary type condition when using rownum. Maximum or minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use at least one Summary column, Netsuite will not display any column without Summary Type defined, so you need to add that to your Rownum column too. So here is a working example:
[image]

And the result is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the formula numeric `{rownum}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the rownum without the braces in your formula..
[image: Formula with rownum]

[image: Preview of results with rownum]